# Does installing the clockworkmod recovery require rooting galaxy s2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, clockworkmod-recovery

Does installing the clockworkmod recovery require you to root galaxy s2 gt-i9100?

In the link [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II%3a_Full_Update_Guide#Installing_the_ClockworkMod_Recovery)
it seems the rooting is not required. However I have read that rooting is required for installing the CWM

Can anybody help with this? I am complete noob!!!

I am trying to install Cyanogenmod on my galaxy s2

Model number: GT-I9100

Baseband version: I9100DDLPB

Kernel version: 3.0.15-1056084 dpi@DELL168 #3 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 22 22:55:24 KST 2012

Build number: IMM76D.XWLPW

Comment: to flash the ROM I am almost certain you need to root your phone. For CWM maybe not, but if you are going to flash in CM then you need to get rid of the chains

Answer (score 2):

In general, no you should be able to install CWM with needing to root, but most of the tutorials I have seen for the S2 GT-I9100 involve rooting the device.

Here are a couple links that may be of interest to you.  I do not think you will need to root to install CWM.

**As always, proceed with caution when flashing.**

[Galaxy S II GT-i9100 Install CWM & Root](http://forum.jakar.co/android-hack/1343090094/)

[Samsung GT-I9000 Galaxy S CyanogenMod install: Flash ClockworkMod Recovery](http://www.cpkb.org/wiki/Samsung_GT-I9000_Galaxy_S_CyanogenMod_install#3._Flash_ClockworkMod_Recovery)

[INDEX of GUIDES/TUTORIALS: SGS2 GT-I9100](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1826497)

Answer (score 0):

I installed CM10.1.3 and CWM on my unrooted GT-i9100 just two weeks ago. You do NOT need root to install CWM, and you do NOT need root to install CM10. However, installing CM10 rooted my phone automatically.